# calculate uploaded data on server by java script

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload large size of data (not file) on server by Ajax (XMLHttpRequest) I need to calculate uploaded data on server. I am using below code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

formData.append('supplierListing', JSON.stringify(excelPostData));

formData.append('jobName', document.getElementById('jobNameInput').value);

formData.append('additionalHeader', addHeader);

xhr.open('post', '/primeChoice/sheet', true);

xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
  clearInterval (counterInt);
  document.getElementById ('uploadCounter').innerHTML = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100) + '%';
}

xhr.onloadstart = function (e) {
  document.getElementById ('uploadCounter').innerHTML = '0%';
}  

xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
      document.getElementById("progressBar").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("uploadSheetStatus").style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
      },3000);
    }
  }
}

xhr.onerror = function(e) {
  showInfo('An error occurred while submitting the form.');
};  

xhr.onload = function() {
  showInfo(this.statusText);
};

xhr.send(formData);
```

when I execute this code, I get the response as 0%, 85%, 100% only. while it should be like increasing progressing number like 0%, 1%, 2%, ...., 100%.

means, for a long time the execution call does not redirect from "onloadstart" event to "onprogress" events, and it shows "0%" progress for a long time. but when compiler reaches at "onprogress" state/event, it shows only 2 response as 85% and 100%.

How can I improve this process So I can get the uploaded data size on real-time?

Answer (score -1):

I worked hard to resolve this issue. you can not resolve this issue through Javascript only. you have to use socket programming. it will help to display the result at runtime. 
let me explain my answer,
node.js

```
const express = require('express');
let server =  app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('%s App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode', chalk.green('✓'), app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.send('Sent a message 4seconds after connection!');    
  console.log(' %s sockets connected', io.engine.clientsCount);    
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log("disconnect: ", socket.id);
  });
});

app.set('socketio', io);
```

in my controller,

```
var io = req.app.get('socketio');
connection.query('INSERT INTO [MY TABLE NAME] SET ?', row, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error)
                throw error;

            let percentage =  parseInt (Math.ceil ((i/sheetData.length)*100));
            io.sockets.emit('progressBar',{ progressPercentage: (percentage > 100) ? 100 : percentage, user: row.user});
        });
```

In jade/view,

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.on('message',function(data) {
    console.log (data);
  });
  socket.on('progressBar',function(data) {
    document.getElementById ('uploadCounter').innerHTML = null;
    document.getElementById ('uploadCounter').innerHTML = data.progressPercentage + '%';
  });
});
```

I believe this approach will help you to display upload progress in run-time.